# How to compare 2 existing columns AS a new field

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to compare 2 existing columns in a PLSQL query and capture the result in a new field called "SEEN".

Its throwing an error, I'm sure I'm missing something basic here.

The line in question is:

```
LAST_TOUCH == USER_ID AS SEEN,
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT distinct CASE_ID, CASE_ID as ID, 
            NAME AS PRIORITY,
            FNN,
            NRF_CONTRAVENTION_ID as CURRENTNRF,
            CUSTOMER_NAME, 
            -- user_id AS OWNER, -- you should be using ownerid 
           from esd_database -- Apoorva
            TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LASTMODIFIEDDATE, 
'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as UPDATEDATE,
            LAST_TOUCH,
            ROUND(CURRENT_DATE - CREATEDDATE) AS WDO,
            STATUS,
            REQUIRED_DATE AS FIELD_APT_DATE, 
         -- Apoorva/Deepa, please check my join here in the V_NRF_TABLE_TE
            ESA,
            FSA,
            REGION,
            LAST_TOUCH == USER_ID AS SEEN,
            case when followupNOTES is not null then SUBSTR(followupNOTES, 0, 40)
            || ' ...'
            end notes
            from V_NRF_TABLE_TE
            where
            :userid = user_id
            -- previously=> user_id = :userid
            and status != 'Complete'
            and function = 'TE'
            ORDER BY WDO DESC
```

Comment: `==` should just be `=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `'=='` operator in SQL and you may not have a boolean expression as a column in Oracle in a select statement (SQL).

You could use  a `CASE WHEN` expression

```
CASE WHEN LAST_TOUCH = USER_ID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as seen
```